# Is there an R package for continuous time longitudinal binary responses?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, binary-data, panel-data

The `bild` package appears to be an excellent package for serial binary responses.  But it is for discrete time.  I would like to specify a smooth function of time for the odds ratio connection of the current response Y with binary responses measured at earlier times, or at least a first-order Markov version of this.  I believe this is called alternating logistic regression.  Does anyone know of an R package that handles continuous time, i.e., measurement times can be at any follow-up time?  I don't need random effects in the model.

Comment: I haven't used it, but for alternating logistic regression, a quick search turned up this ALR package:  http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/carey/vcwww_4.html

Comment: Thanks for this comment.  The best I can tell from the documentation, alr is only for discrete time.

Answer (score 1):

The R package [orth](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/orth/) may be of some help.  Here's a [vignette](http://www.unc.edu/~kby/R_Splus/fullVersion2.pdf).  See also the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/orth/orth.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user22299. Would you mind expanding on this w/ a few sentences to say what the package can do, & why you think it might be the answer?

Comment: The authors programmed the combinatoric calculations by generating a combinatoric dataset, making it not computationally efficient enough for large $N$.  They perhaps did that to make it work in SAS IML.  In addition, I can't tell if their method has the properties of a full likelihood approach, i.e., whether it is robust to non-random dropout as generalized least squares and mixed effects models are.  Their method is akin to the non-full-likelihood alternating logistic regression (ALR), implying you have to use multiple imputation on top of ALR to make the missing values missing at random.

Comment: In 2013, `orth` was removed from the CRAN repository.

Answer (score 0):

There is the package [bild](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bild/index.html), which stands for "*bi*nary *l*ongitudinal *d*ata analysis." It may help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Jung Woo June. I didn't downvote you, but would you mind expanding on this w/ a few sentences to say what the package can do, & why you think it might be the answer? The sparseness of this answer may have been the reason behind the downvote.

Comment: I think that `bild` only handles the discrete time case.